# Colecciones con genericidad. ¿Porqué me sale un error cuando pongo implements?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber porque en mi código cuando pongo en la cabecera de la clase implements (interfaz), me sale un error. El error es en la siguiente linea, y ademas me aparece subrayado en rojo (uso NetBeans):

```
public boolean add(E e) { //Situado en la clase BagList
```

El código del programa es el siguiente:

El interface Collection:

```
package ejercicio2;

import java.util.Iterator;

public interface Collection <E> {
    boolean add(E e);
    boolean addAll (Collection <? extends E> c);
    void clear();
    boolean contains (Object o );
    boolean isEmpty();
    public Iterator <E> iterator();
    int size();
}
```

El interface Bag:

```
package ejercicio2;

public interface Bag <E> extends Collection {
    E extract();
    void emptyIn(Bag <? super E> b);
}
```

La clase BagList:

```
package ejercicio2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Random;


public class BagList<E> implements Bag{
    private final ArrayList <E> elemento = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public E extract() {  
        int i;
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        i = aleatorio.nextInt(elemento.size());
        return elemento.get(i);
    }
    @Override
     public void emptyIn(Bag b) {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < elemento.size(); i++){
            b.add(elemento.get(i));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        boolean añadir = false;
        if (elemento.add(e)){
            añadir = true;
        }
        return añadir;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
        boolean añadir = false;
        if (elemento.addAll((Collection<? extends E>) c)){
            añadir = true;
        }
        return añadir;
    }
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        elemento.clear();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        boolean contiene = false;
        if (elemento.contains(o)){
            contiene = true;
        }
        return contiene;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean vacia = false;
        if (elemento.isEmpty())
            vacia = true;
        return vacia;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return elemento.iterator();
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return elemento.size();
    }
}
```

El enunciado del problema por si os sirve de más ayuda es el siguiente:

Una bolsa puede ser definida como una colección de elementos entre los que no se establece ninguna relación de orden. Una vez que introducimos un elemento en la bolsa no podremos decir en qué posición va a quedar dicho elemento con respecto al resto de elementos de la bolsa. De la misma forma, al extraer un elemento de la bolsa todos tienen la misma posibilidad de ser extraídos. Teniendo esto en cuenta crea una interfaz Bag, que herede del interfaz Collection y cuyo objetivo sea definir el comportamiento de una bolsa. Bag debe tener al menos los siguientes métodos:

boolean add(E e). Añade el elemento especificado a la bolsa, devuelve true
si la bolsa ha cambiado después de realizar la operación.

boolean addAll(Collection c). Añade a la bolsa todos los
elementos de la colección pasada por parámetro. Devuelve true si la bolsa ha
cambiado después de realizar la operación.

void clear(). Elimina todos los elementos de la bolsa.

boolean contains(Object o). Comprueba si la bolsa contiene el elemento
pasado por parámetro.

boolean isEmpty(). Devuelve true si la bolsa no tiene elementos.

public Iterator iterator(). Devuelve un iterador que permite recorrer
los elementos de la bolsa.

int size(). Devuelve el número de elementos de la bolsa.

E extract(). Extrae un elemento de la bolsa, como todos los elementos tienen
la misma probabilidad de ser extraídos deben usarse números pseudoaleatorios
para decidir qué elemento debe ser seleccionado.

emptyIn(Bag b). Vacía el contenido de la bolsa actual en la bolsa
pasada por parámetro. La bolsa actual queda vacía.

Crea ahora una clase que realice el interfaz Bag y le de una implementación a sus métodos (por ejemplo BagList si almacenáis los elementos en una lista). Como vemos, salvo los métodos extract y emptyIn, el resto son métodos del interfaz Collection.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se te olvidó especificar el genérico en las 2 líneas siguientes:

```
public interface Bag <E> extends Collection {
```

y

```
public class BagList<E> implements Bag{
```

Estas deberían ser:

```
public interface Bag <E> extends Collection<E> {
```

y

```
public class BagList<E> implements Bag<E>{
```

Por no haber especificado el `<E>` en ambos casos, es como si hubieras especificado `Collection<Object>` y `Bag<Object>`, que definitivamente no es lo que quieres y resulta en el error que recibes.